# Wear project - attr 'android:windowSwipeToDismiss'

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

Has anyone else run into the build error:

> Error:(127, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:windowSwipeToDismiss'.

When building the new wear project?  I'm past the setup instructions http://developer.android.com/preview/google-play-services-wear.html and have the new play services sdks installed, but I feel like I'm missing something or have a wrong dependency but can't track it down.

the error occurs in values.xml

```
<style name="Theme.Wearable.Modal">
    <item name="android:windowSwipeToDismiss">false</item>
</style>
```

I'm creating a new project and have even tried to delete and create another new project.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the following line in build.gradle? (I am assuming you are using Android Studio) Pasting build.gradle would help.

>>dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
}

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what is in there.

Comment: Ok that's my build.gradle. https://gist.github.com/thorikawa/2071171e573d096f5ff0 Is there any difference from yours?

Comment: That's it, Poly, thanks for your build, you should post it as a reply. What is crucial here is compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion.

Comment: Yeah, that was my problem too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This theme attribute is newly defined in Android API Level 20. Be sure you're targeting android-20 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Check your build.gradle has a line `compileSdkVersion 20` Sync your gradle and check for an opportunity to install this library.